# Is TCP packet origin IP address included in packet?

Tags: tcp, ip-address, packet, packet-sniffers

I am working on a project that sorts packets based on sender IP address (port does not matter). I am wondering if sender IP address is included in packet information.  If so, how might I access that number using Java?.

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, and you can access it via `Socket.getRemoteAddress()` and friends in the case of TCP, and the corresponding methods of `DatagramPacket` in the case of UDP.